# crashing when I using AVX function

Tags: c, clang, simd, avx

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "x86intrin.h"

void dd_m(double *clo, int m) 
{
int j;
__m256d *vclo = (__m256d *)clo;
__m256d al=_mm256_set_pd(0,0,0,0);
__m256d clo_n=_mm256_set_pd(0,0,0,0);
int i;
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        al = _mm256_add_pd(vclo[m/4*j+i] , clo_n);
    }
}
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

int m;
double* zlo;
int i;


m=(int)pow(2,8);

zlo=(double *)_mm_malloc(sizeof(double) * m*m,32);
for (i=0;i<m*m;i++) {
    zlo[i]=0.0;
}
dd_m(zlo, m);

_mm_free(zlo);

return 0;
}
```

Here's my code.
It generate an error

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x102900000)"

inside for loop.

I used latest xcode with clang.

What should I do?

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and indicate which line the fault occurs on.

Comment: BTW, it's worth reading [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Comment: You should debug at what values of `j` and `i` this error occurs, check if there is an index out of range and work out the formula. Hint:  `for (i = 0; i + 3 < m; i++)`

Comment: If you want this to run *really* fast, you're going to want to use multiple accumulators to hide the latency of FP add.  On Skylake, `vaddpd` has 4 cycle latency but 2 per cycle throughput (same as 256-bit loads), so you need to keep 8 vector adds in flight at once to bottleneck on ALU / L1d cache throughput.  Compilers can't unroll FP reductions with multiple accumulators for you unless you use `-ffast-math`.

Comment: `m=(int)pow(2,8);` => `1 << 8`

Comment: al = _mm256_add_pd(vclo[m/4*j+i] , clo_n); This line made error. When variables are i=192, j=253, make error.

Answer (score 3):

By casting your `clo` to point to 256-bit vectors as `vclo`, your row-length is divided by four, you changed it in the index computation, but not in the inner loop over `i`.

```cpp
for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < m/4; i++) { // in vclo, the rows are only m/4 long
        al = _mm256_add_pd(vclo[m/4*j+i] , clo_n);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. However, it seems effective only 2 for loops. What should I do if there are another loop... like that...
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < l; k++) {
                for (i = 0; i< m/4; i++) {
                     p2 = _mm256_add_pd(vclo[m*k/4+i],vclo[jl/4+k]));
                }
}
} This case would make error

Comment: Draw a picture of your matrix, and visualise how the data elements are accesses inside the loop nest to really understand the code.

The rows of your matrix are chunked into SIMD-registers of 4 doubles. Every index going through the rows (that is right of the `+` in an `[...*...+...]` access) can only go from 0 to (row-length/4 - 1). If you go through the columns with the same index, i.e. k, it needs a different range from 0 to (column-height - 1). You might want to use `clo` and build one SIMD register with 4 elements of the row by casting, and one with 4 elements of a column by gathering.